# Help dealing with a linear equation with 200 variables

Tags: linear-algebra

So this is a bit of an odd one, and I can see what I need to do from a simplistic maths approach but I am wondering if there is an easier way of going about things.

I've got a linear equation representing various x and y points in principle component space, and what we want to do is forward model the resulting minimum and maximum points for each axis. I should add that the analysis was completed by someone else and using some software that spits out the equation as if each X & Y is an individual PCA variable. I don't necessarily agree with the approach, but offered to help this person but am now stumped myself!

The equation for each component axis is something like this:

$PC = a_1x_1 - b_1y_1+...a_{100}x_{100} - b_{100}y_{100}$

I've called the gradients (correct term?!) for each point a and b as they all seem to be unique/different.

As a first glance I would rearrange to get each $x$ and $y$ coordinate out, but that is a lot of equations. Does anyone have any other smarter suggestions?

We want to take a value of the PC space and get out the 100 coordinates.

Comment: I'm a bit confused about what you are trying to do. Are you trying to compute all the $(x_1,y_1), \ldots, (x_{100},y_{100})$ given the value of PC for each equation? If so, perhaps using a least squares solver is a good approach.

Comment: Hey no worries, I wrote that in a hurry. I'm trying to take the equation for each PC axis, put in some maximum values, and then get back out the corresponding 100 $x$ and $y$ values out for whatever his PC analysis is showing. 

My colleague who has generated this data seems to think he can define shapes this way, so the idea is that if there is some kind of trend in the way he's defined the shapes using these 100 coordinates, then you should be able to get a sort of end-member shape at each axis. 

Hope that helps

Comment: I should add that yeah your answer is correct, ultimately we want each $(x_1,y_1)$ but we have a single linear equation containing all of the points. 

I guess what we would need out is each point for a given value of $PC1$ or $PC2$. Say $PC1=30$, $PC2=0$ or both being 30. etc